# Is there a way to read data from json to html realtime?

Tags: jquery, html, json, knockout.js, telegram

For a school project I write telegram messages realtime to a JSON file. Now I want to update my HTML when a new message comes in the JSON. My HTML works together with JQuery/Knockout.js. What is the best way to do this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var viewModel = function() {
   console.log('test');
   $.getJSON( '/apps/telegram/getmessages', function( data ) {
   //console.log(data["messages"]);
   var jsondata = data["messages"];
   console.log(jsondata);
   for(index = 0; index<jsondata.length; ++ index){
    console.log(jsondata[index]);
    var message = jsondata[index]["message"];
    var firstname = jsondata[index]["first_name"];
    console.log(message);
    $('#messages').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
    }
})
.error(function(error){
  console.log(error);

    });
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
})
```

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] and [Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) especially the part about homework and re-formulate using a [mcve]

Comment: the code looks broadly ok. What exactly is not working?

Comment: tell us what is not working

Comment: @ADyson yes this code works but doesn't update my HTML realtime, it only updates when I refresh which is logical. Now i want to update my HTML realtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update in near-realtime, the simplest way utilising the code you already have is to set an interval at which the code will ask the server for updated data. This will run the same code repeatedly at the interval you specify:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  console.log('test');
  $.getJSON( '/apps/telegram/getmessages', function( data ) {
    //console.log(data["messages"]);
    var jsondata = data["messages"];
    console.log(jsondata);

    for(index = 0; index<jsondata.length; ++ index){
      console.log(jsondata[index]);
      var message = jsondata[index]["message"];
      var firstname = jsondata[index]["first_name"];
      console.log(message);
      $('#messages').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
    }
  })
  .error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });      
},
1000); //1000 milliseconds (1 second). Change the value to whatever you need.
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval for more details.

Comment: This doesn't really seems to work, I still have to refresh to see any changes.

Comment: you shouldn't need to. Can you see in the console whether the function is running every 1 second? And is it returning data with new messages in it? The only flaw in this will be if your getJSON function takes more than 1 second to return a result, it might be getting a bit out of sync.

Comment: It works but there is one problem : every second he prints the new message over and over again. Is there a way that i can print it only once?

Comment: one way is get the server to only return messages that have not been returned before (it will keep a record of it). Or another way, possibly a bit more robust, is to get the client to send the ID of the last message received when it makes the request, so then the server will know only to return messages later than that. If you want to do something more sophisticated, you could ditch this code entirely and look into using WebSockets, that way it would be easier to for the server to "push" messages to the client as soon as it receives them.

Comment: Thanks, I went for the sockets.